# How to show the index of a certain object?

Tags: java

I want to return the "i" from the last method to the main method as the index.  I cant' figure out how to return the "i" since its encased in the if statement.
The code is supposed to be able to tell the user where the name was in the array.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
/**
 *  A simple array activity where the user will provide data for an array
    that will be stored into an array. It will allow the user to search
    any name in the array.
    Katelynn Schoenrock
    Ken Nguyen
    Computer Science 1301
    Activity 2
    11/29/2016
 */
public class Array{
    private static Student[] data = new Student[10];

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(int i = 0; i< data.length; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter Student name");
            String name = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Birthdate");
            String birthDate = keyboard.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter Address");
            String address = keyboard.nextLine();
            new Student(name, birthDate, address);
            data[i] = new Student(name, birthDate, address);
        }
        String nameToLookFor = create();
        int Index = Search(nameToLookFor);
        System.out.println("Object's Index: " + Index);


    }

    /**
     * This method obtains the user's input and returns the Student object
     * @param return nameToLookFor
     */
    public static String create(){
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a name to search");
        String nameToLookFor = keyboard.nextLine();
        return nameToLookFor;

    }

    /**
     * This method allows for the user to search any given name.
     * @param return The index of the object
     */
    public static int Search(String nameToLookFor){
        for(int i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(data[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToLookFor) ){ 
             System.out.println(data[i]);
         }

     }

   }

}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(i)`? I don't get what you mean.

Comment: I want to return i, so i'll have the index where it says "int Index = Search(nameToLookFor)

Comment: There are a number of ways to solve this kind of problem: (1) `return` it from the method as suggested in Tim's answer, which often works; (2) declare `int i;` outside the loop and don't use `int` in the `for` statement; (3) declare some other variable and assign `i` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just return the index from your `Search()` method:

```
public static int Search(String nameToLookFor) {
    int NOT_FOUND = -1;
    for (int i=data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (data[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToLookFor) ) { 
            System.out.println(data[i]);
            return i;
        }
    }

    return NOT_FOUND;
}
```

Here I am returning a value of `-1` if the name is never found.  This should be OK because strings in Java cannot have a negative index.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the variable external to your loop and also break when it finds the value

```
 public static int Search(String nameToLookFor){
    int i = -1;  // not found value
    for(i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    if(data[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(nameToLookFor) ){ 
         System.out.println(data[i]);
         break;
     }
     return i;

 }
```